# Why is req.busboy undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, busboy

I am using `connect-busboy` in Express.js 4 in order to upload files. I have added `app.use(busboy({ immediate: true });` in app.js. My route handler looks like this:

```
router.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    var fstream;

    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    console.log(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldName, file, fileName) {
        console.log('Uploading ' + fileName + '...');
        fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/data/' + fileName);
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function () {
            res.end('ok');
        });
    });
});
```

The `console.log(req.busboy);` returns `undefined`. Why?!??!

Comment: Is your `app.use(busboy({ immediate: true }));` *before* your routes? Also, you probably shouldn't set `immediate: true`, especially since you are doing `req.pipe(req.busboy);` yourself.

Comment: Yes, it is. Even without the ```immediate: true```, the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorted it out! It turns out that the `contentType` should be `form/multi-part`, which wasn't the case

Comment: Could you be more specific. The content type on what?

Answer (score 1):

For multi-part forms:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary63SFlxFGGDbxCqT7
```

The boundaries are randomly generated so in order to get this to work in Node Express it's recommend to set this header to be 'undefined', the browser will take care of the rest.  For example:

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://youurl.com,
        data: data,
        // Remove the 'Content-Type' header for multipart form submission
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    });
```

For anyone that has the same question as Jordan:

> "Could you be more specific.  The content type on what?"

It means setting the 'Content-Type' header in the request sent from your browser to the web server.  For example, setting the content type header to JSON looks like this:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```